# CSS modules with Sass and Gatsby

Tags: sass, gatsby, css-modules

How can Sass be used with CSS modules in Gatsby on conditional classes?

I have tried the following:

`menu.js`

```
import menuStyles from './menu.module.scss';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const Menu = ({ open }) => {
  return (
    <nav className={classNames(menuStyles.menu, { isOpen: open })}>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

`menu.module.scss`:

```
.menu {
  background: green;

  &.isOpen {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

An `onClick` event updates the `open` prop, and I can see the `isOpen` class being added and removed as expected.
The problem is that the CSS isn't applied to it: the background remains green. Looking in the Chrome Network tab I can see that the styles are applied to the class `menu-module--isOpen--DyE73` and not just `isOpen`:

```
.menu-module--menu--2cKbx {
  background: green;
}
.menu-module--menu--2cKbx.menu-module--isOpen--DyE73 {
  background: blue;
}
```

When not using CSS modules (`import './menu.scss';` and `<nav className={classNames('menu', { isOpen: open })}>`), the styles are applied properly in both cases.

How can Sass be used with CSS modules to style the conditional `isOpen` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
<nav className={classNames(menuStyles.menu, { [menuStyles.isOpen]: open })}>
```

The difference is that I replaced `isOpen` with `[menuStyles.isOpen]` (the square brackets representing [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)).

Just like `menu`, the CSS rule `isOpen` also gets a dynamic, locally scoped name so you need to make sure to import its name from the CSS module to.